# How to find 2 matching records comparing two fields in one table to two fields in another table?

Tags: ms-access-2010

Using MS Access 2010, I have two tables that I need to compare and only retrieve the matches.

Table [EE] has 5 fields:

```
Field4, SSN, Birthdate, Address1, Address2
```

Table [UPDATED] has fields:

```
Field4, DOB
```

and several others not relevant to thus question.

I need to find all records in [EE] from fields Field4 AND Birthdate that have a matching values in BOTH Field4 and DOB in [UPDATED]. I have tried INNER JOIN and it is returning me several duplicates.  I have tried:

```
SELECT EE.Birthdate, EE.Field4
FROM EE, UPDATED
WHERE (EE.Birthdate = UPDATED.DOB) 
AND (EE.Field4 = UPDATED.FIELD4)
```

And

```
SELECT EE.Birthdate, EE.Field4
FROM INNER JOIN UPDATED ON EE.Birthdate = UPDATED.DOB)
  AND (EE.Field4 = UPDATED.FIELD4)
```

I am getting a lot of duplicate records and only want the records that appear in BOTH tables.

Comment: I think there is actually a query in the wizard that will help you do what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably actually duplicates. Add the `DISTINCT` keyword to eliminate duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EE.Birthdate, EE.Field4
FROM EE
JOIN UPDATED ON EE.Birthdate = UPDATED.DOB
  AND EE.Field4 = UPDATED.FIELD4
```

I also fixed a few syntax errors.

Also, always prefer using proper join syntax.